# CallOut Class not Executing

Tags: apex, callout

I was hoping someone can help looker over this callout flow to see if I may have configured something wrong.  I'm not seeing any new logs when this should be invoked from Process Builder so I don't think this is executing.

In short, I am collecting a ContactID from Process Builder, and executing a callout to an external API.

The API endpoint is added as a remote site.

Any help into a direction would greatly be appreciated!

HelperClass:

```
public class ContactReferralLostHelper {
@InvocableMethod
//Method that accepts the ContactIDs from Process Builder and process through Influitive's API
public static void updateContactStateInfo(List<Id> ContactIds) {
    Id contactId = ContactIds[0];

    Contact con = [SELECT Id, AdvocateHub__Referral_ID__c FROM Contact WHERE Id=: contactId];

    if (con.Id !=null) {
        ContactReferralLost.updateReferral(con.Id, con.AdvocateHub__Referral_ID__c);
    }

}}
```

API Callout Class:

```
global class ContactReferralLost {
    public static HttpCalloutMock mock = null; // this is populated while call is from test class

public class Message {
    public Referral referral;  // referral information

}

//Referral information
public class Referral{
    public String feedback;
    public String id;
    public String status;

}

// this method convert the message object to the JSON string which is used to send information
// to the gilmour Influitive over http request in url
private static String toJsonString(Message m) {
    return JSON.serializePretty(m.referral.feedback);
}    

/**
 * it will send the updated referral information to the Influitive API.
 **/
@future (callout=true)
public static void updateReferral(Id contactId, String referral_id) {

    Referral r = new Referral();
    r.id = referral_id;
    r.feedback = 'This referral was already an existing customer relationship';
    r.status = 'lost';

    // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (PUT) as well as the endpoint  
    String url='https://api.influitive.com/referrals/' + r.id + '/milestones/' + r.status + '?_HttpMethod=PUT';
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override','PUT');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Token {{AuthToken}}');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('X_ORG_ID', '{{ORGID}}');



    Message m = new Message();
    m.referral.feedback = r.feedback;



    String body = toJsonString(m);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(body);
    System.debug('this is the body');
    System.debug(body);

    HttpResponse res = null;

    if (Test.isRunningTest() && (mock!=null)) {
       res = mock.respond(req);
    } else {
        res = h.send(req);
    }

    System.debug('Response: '+ res.getBody());

   // Add notes to opportunity

    note n = new note();
    n.parentId= contactId; //Id of the opportunity for which you want to add this note
    n.body=res.getBody(); // body of the note. this should be populated from the notes field that you have shown in the screenshot
    n.title='Resonse from update Referral call to gilmour influitive at ' + datetime.now(); // the title of the note
    n.isPrivate=false;  // if private it will be visible only for the owner and any user with modify all permission
    insert n; //insert the record

}
}
```

Comment: did you debug the invocable method? btw, `if (con.Id !=null)` is not needed as SOQL statement with `Contact` object assignment will throw the error if contact not found

Comment: did you activate the process?

Comment: Yep, the process is activated.  But I didn't add debug to my invokable method but I'll try that to troubleshoot further.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please include some level of detail about what is actually going wrong? What is the observed behavior here? How does it diverge from the desired behavior?

Comment: Thanks for the response Adrian, without any additions to the logs it's hard for me to know what's going wrong, so that's why my post is a little general as I'm not sure if there was something simple I left out to make sure the Apex is executing.   At this point I would just like to see if my APEX executed with either a success or failure. 

I will add some debugging to the invokable method to see if it is being run.